# How to add active class show/hide tabs?

Tags: jquery

What I want to achieve is when I click a tab it adds a class of "active" which works fine but it is showing the wrong content.

So div1 is displaying div2 content and div2 is showing div1 content, my code is a follows:

```
<div class="buttons">
<a id="buttonshowone" class="showsearch active" target="1">Properties For Sale</a>
<a id="buttonshowtwo" class="showsearch" target="2">Properties To Let</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="searchbut">
</div>
<div id="div2" class="searchbut">
</div>
```

My Jquery is as follows:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#div1').show();
    jQuery('#div2').hide();
    jQuery('.showsearch').click(function(){
        jQuery('.searchbut').hide();
        jQuery('#div'+$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: You have two `<div>`s with the same **id**. Should the second one be `<div id="div2" class="searchbut">`?

Comment: Sorry yeah my bad, this is divid2, question amended above.

Comment: What item are you expecting from: `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').attr('target')`? Maybe you should simplify this and separate the operations from the attribute getting. Because it's getting the `siblings`, not `this`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - Thanks for your answer, I am new to Jquery and tabs, I thought it was this part I was going wrong on, whats the alternateive to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of siblings in the chain is selecting the other div, not the one you want. Try this instead:

```
jQuery('#div1').show();
jQuery('#div2').hide();
jQuery('.showsearch').click(function () {
    jQuery('.searchbut').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t106ua25/)**

I also recommend using custom data attributes (`data-`) instead of using the target attrbute here, unless you have some other need for using the target attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#div1').show();
    jQuery('#div2').hide();
    jQuery('.showsearch').click(function(){
        jQuery('.searchbut').hide();
        jQuery('.showsearch.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).not('.active').addClass('active');
        jQuery( '#div'+$(this).data('target') ).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
<a id="buttonshowone" class="showsearch active" data-target="1">Properties For Sale</a>
<a id="buttonshowtwo" class="showsearch" data-target="2">Properties To Let</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="searchbut">div 1
</div>
<div id="div2" class="searchbut">div 2
</div>
```